# Which one is gramatically correct? - I need some help

Tags: grammar

There are two sentences:

1. In artifacts from as early as the Stone Age, mathematics and art can be seen to have fused in the geometric patterns **which decorate** pottery and carpentry.
2. In artifacts from as early as the Stone Age, mathematics and art can be seen to have fused in the geometric patterns **to decorate** pottery and carpentry.

I think the first one is the most suitable option for this sentence, but someone has another idea as option 2 noted above. I'm a bit confused. Hope someone could help.

Answer (score 1):

> fused in the geometric patterns which decorate pottery and carpentry

We're talking about patterns that have been found on actual pottery.

> fused in the geometric patterns to decorate pottery and carpentry

We're talking about patterns more abstractly, in this sentence we don't have actual pottery/carpentry in mind.  This also expresses that it's possible the patterns were intended to decorate, but never actually did for some reason.

If you have a picture of the pottery/carpentry, use *which*.

If you drew the patterns, but don't have actual examples of where they're applied, use *to*.